# nodejs cannot access an exported method Object #<Object> has no method

Tags: node.js, express

i exported some of my variable an a function in nodejs like below:

app.js:

```
var setting;
var savesetting = function(val, callback){ .....}
module.export =setting;
module.export = savesetting;
```

index.js:

```
var appjs = require('app');
appjs.savesettings(0,1);
```

appjs.savesettings(); cause an error which is:

```
Express
500 TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'savesettings'
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
var app = {
   setting:{},
   savesetting : function(val, callback){ .....}
}
module.exports = app;
```

http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: actually, im looking for a way to access variables, function of a js file in another one.am i right to do it in this way??

Comment: i wrote the code for app.js, index.js should work with no modification.